# Properly Tokenize R language in VS Code Vim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim-plugin, vscodevim

In the VSCode Vim plugin, there are various normal mode commands that depend on the boundaries of the word/token under the cursor (e.g. `*`, `w`, `e`, etc).  These don't work well with the R language which uses the dot (`.`) as an ordinary token character and not as an operator as most languages do.

This means that, for example, if you search (`*`) for a variable under the cursor like `my.data`, the vim plugin will either search for `my` or `data`, but not `my.data` as it should.

Curiously, with the R plugin installed (which has the [correct syntax definitions](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/blob/ce8ae9c31e08c38471aac861a2207fe3716776fe/syntax/r.json#L135-L144)), built in VSCode features like the [Rename Symbol Command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol) work as they should (e.g. hitting `F2` when the cursor is over `my.data` will replace the whole variable and not just `my` or `data`).

Is there a way to get VSCode Vim to respect the R syntax via user configuration or would this require an update to the R or VSCode vim plugins?

Comment: does the `editor.wordSeparators` setting have any effect here?

Comment: @starball Yes! -- but not as a language specific setting (e.g. `"[r]": { "editor.wordSeparators": "\`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",<>/?" },`, which sadly defeats the point b/c this setting (omitting the dot as a separator) would apply to all languages including those that use the dot as an operator (e.g. almost all of them).

Comment: It works if I put it at the top level of the user settings (which applies to all languages) but not if I put it with my other [R specific settings](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Recommended-extensions-and-configuration#dots-in-variablefunction-names) `"[r]":{...}`.  Maybe it's a bug in my setup.  Reading the [vim plugin code](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/textobject/textobject.ts#L301-L302), it makes sense that this is the correct setting though.

Comment: FWIW, I toggled this setting in and out of my language specific settings and used the `Developer: reload window` command to confirm that (for me) it's only working as a global setting.  Same is true if I uninstall the R extension

Comment: Also, this isn't just specific to the R language settings.  For example, dropping the square brackets from the `wordSeparators` (as in `SELECT [table].[field] ...`) for sql files only works if the setting is set at the top level and not in the `"[sql]":{...}` language specific settings

Comment: weird... it's apparently using VS Code's `Position` class, but the methods it's calling from its instances aren't documented, and I don't see similar methods defined in the source Code... Ex. `nextWordStart`. Nor can I find them defined in the Monaco source code. Oh hm... it's monkey patching them onto the `Position` prototype... see https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/common/motion/position.ts#L417.

Comment: what if you use the `vim.iskeyword` setting instead of the `editor.wordSeparators` setting? [They're supposed to alias each other](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/configuration/configuration.ts#L373), but I wonder if there's any funny business going on with respect to that. or have you touched the `vim.iskeyword` setting at all anywhere already?

Comment: possibly historically related: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/7123

Comment: I just installed VS Code Vim and am trying it out myself. `vim.iskeyword` can't be set as a language override setting, but `editor.wordSeparators` can, and it does seem to take effect for ctrl+left/right, but weird things are happening when taking `.` out of it.

Comment: okay correction. weird things happen when using `*` to search forward, but using `viw` to select the inner word works as expected when setting ``"[r]": {"editor.wordSeparators":"`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",<>/?"}``. Do you observe the same behaviour?

Comment: Nope.  For me, using `viw` only selects the `my` or `data` of `my.data` -- even when setting the `editor.separators` at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

The VS Code Vim extension is *supposed* to honour its `vim.iskeyword` setting, which is really just a higher-priority alias of the `editor.wordSeparators` setting for the Vim extension. If you don't set `vim.iskeyword`, it will fall back to `editor.wordSeparators`, and if neither are set, it defaults to using `` /\\()"\':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`?- ``. The source code for this behaviour is in https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/src/configuration/configuration.ts. Interestingly, `vim.iskeyword` isn't registered as a language-overridable setting, but doing something like this *should* work:

```json
"[r]": {
  "editor.wordSeparators": "", // <- put whatever you want in here that doesn't include ".".
},
```

I've tested that it works for selecting the inner word in visual mode (<kbd>viw</kbd>). Weird things happen with forward word search (<kbd>*</kbd>, but I think that's probably just a bug, in which case I'd suggest that you raise a bug ticket). If you want to trace the source code for this, you can go through the following:

- https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/textobject/textobject.ts#L285
- https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/common/motion/position.ts#L409
- https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/textobject/word.ts#L52
- https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/textobject/word.ts#L75
- https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/textobject/util.ts#L1
- https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/textobject/word.ts#L16
- https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/0a6d8dc48747cae3398b68c931cd7aefbbe140ca/src/textobject/word.ts#L318

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: Seems there is [already an open issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/8190) (albeit the OP was a little unclear...)